# Converting hexadecimal to decimal error in C

Tags: c

```
int htoi(char s[]) {
  int c;
  int sum = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]) - 2; (c = tolower(s[i])) >= 'a' && (c = tolower(s[i]) <= 'f'); i--) {
    int temp = (int) pow(16, counter) * (c - 87);
    sum += temp;
    counter++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I am calling the method with:

```
int main()
{
  char s[] = "FFF";
  printf("%d\n", htoi(s));
}
```

I'm just starting to learn C. I'm trying to create a method that converts hexadecimal to decimal, but the following code doesn't work. It's outputting -87 on my terminal, and I'm not sure why.

EDIT: Just realized my code doesn't take into account actual digits, but either way it doesn't work when I input "FFF" as the input array.

Comment: `sizeof(s)` here is the size of a pointer - not the size of an array.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: My objective was to iterate from the end of the array to the beginning. Could you tell me how to get the size of the array? I thought arrays were pretty much equivalent to pointers in C!

Comment: Arrays are not pointers - pointers are not arrays.  Pass into the function the array size.

Comment: How do I get the size of an array then? I originally did s.size() but that's incorrect.

Comment: "How do I get the size of an array then" --> post the calling code that has the _array_.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your code that calls `htoi`.

Comment: Alright, I hope I did what's needed. Sorry, it's been a while since I used stack overflow.

Comment: note: `(c = tolower(s[i]) <= 'f')` is also wrong and it will assign `0` or `1` to `c`, according to the comparision result.

Comment: @JustinHu Why do you want to use the array size, not the length of the string?

Comment: There is no particular reason. I was just trying to see how things worked in C. To my knowledge, the sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]) segment of code calculates the number of bytes of the array and divides it by the number of bytes of one component of the array. This would then give me the number of elements in the array, which I can use to iterate through.

Comment: Do you just want to write `htoi` or would using `strtoul` be an option that has done it for you already?

Comment: I want to write ```htoi```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code has troubles:

It incorrectly uses `sizeof(s)` to find the size of "array" `char s[]`, but `s` is a pointer.  The calling code's `s` is an array, yet it converts to the address of the first element (a pointer) when used as a function argument.  In particular `char s[]` is a pointer when used as a function parameter.

It assigns `c` to the result of the compare `c = tolower(s[i]) <= 'f'` rather than the lowercase value. [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245438/converting-hexadecimal-to-decimal-error-in-c#comment102862768_58245438)

It does not handle `'0' - '9'`.

Instead, simple walk the string pointed to by `s`, first (most significant digit) to last (least).

```
int htoi(const char *s) {
  int sum = 0;
  while (isxdigit((unsigned char) *s)) {
    int digit_value;
    int char_value = (unsigned char) *s++;  // Get unsigned value and advance s
    if (isdigit(char_value)) {
      digit_value = *s - '0'; 
    } else {
      digit_value = tolower(char_value) - 'a' + 10; 
    }
    sum = sum * 16 + digit_value;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

Rarely does code need a *signed* hexadecimal value.  Consider returning an `unsigned` type.

```
unsigned htou(const char *s) { 
  unsigned  sum = 0;
  ...
```